# Django - estender template do admin

Tags: django, django-templates

alguém poderia indicar a melhor forma de estender o template do django? e qual a melhor forma de compartilhar um template com a área adminstrativa e do site.

Estou usando django versão 1.8.6 e django-bootstrap3

obrigado.

Comment: "Melhor" em que sentido? Quanto à área administrativa, ao fazer `collecttemplate` todos os templates usados pelo `admin` vão parar numa pasta, então você pode ver qual é sua estrutura e então customizá-lo (não tenho experiência com isso, mas creio que o ideal é copiar o template padrão para uma de suas apps - preservando o caminho - e alterá-lo lá).

Comment: Entendi @mgibsonbr. Eu quis dizer "melhor" no sentido de implementação, vi alguns exemplos onde copiavam o template mestre que fica no django da máquina, outros pegam o template de github. 
obrigado pelas dicas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo a resposta [desse post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates), você pode usar o template loader do [djangosnippets](https://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1376/) e extender o template do admin de uma forma bem fácil. Veja o exemplo:

```
{% extends "admin:admin/index.html" %}

{% block sidebar %}
    {{block.super}}
    <div>
        <h1>Extra links</h1>
        <a href="/admin/extra/">My extra link</a>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Não sei se essa é a melhor forma, mas é uma das formas. Vi que o post é antigo, mas acho que a resposta ainda é valida. Abraços